# Checkout files from tortoise svn using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

I was using this command to check out the file using Tortise svn

```
work = "F:\Test"
exe = "C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe"
argu = ("/command:checkout /url:https://Test/help /path:" + str(work))
proc1 = subprocess.Popen([exe, argu])
```

Once I run the this command I can able to see the path in the Checkout directory field in checkout window.

```
F:\Test"\help
```

But if I use ("/command:checkout /url:https://Test/help /path:F:\Test") this  command  then I can able to see following path in the Checkout directory field in checkout window.

```
F:\Test\help
```

Please let me know do we need to provide the complete path in the path variable

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you use escaped backslashes, either

```
 work = "F:\\Test"
```

or (python raw strings)

```
 work = r"F:\Test"
```

Then, try to follow the Popen documentation, i quote:

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. It is recommended to pass args as a sequence if shell is False and as a string if shell is True.

which would look like this:

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen([exe, '/command:checkout', '/url:https://Test/help', '/path:' + str(work)])
```

HTH, I hope i interpreted your question correctly